# How can PrintJobSettings be converted to SRSPrintDirectionSettings?

Tags: printing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a `PrintJobSettings` object, I need to have the `SRSPrintDirectionSettings` to set the print property.

I have a class controller for my report (`SrsReportRunController`).

Can I convert the `PrintJobSettings`?

Answer (score 3):

There are no `PrintJobSetting` and `SRSPrintDirectionSetting` objects in AX.

You probably meant `PrintJobSettings` and `SRSPrintDestinationSettings`.

In this case:

```
SRSPrintDestinationSettings srsPrintDestinationSettings = ReleaseUpdateDB60_Basic::convertPrintJobSettings(printJobSettings);
```